# jquery bind focus / blur events to AJAX loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax, focus, bind, blur

I have this script which works fine to add / remove a class on blur / focus on text inputs and textareas - however I need to bind it to also work on content added after page load via AJAX:

```
 $(function() {
  $('input[type=text], textarea').addClass("idleField"); // reset all ##
  $('input[type=text], textarea').bind("focus", function(event){
      $(this).removeClass("idleField").addClass("focusField");
      if (this.value == this.defaultValue){ 
       this.value = '';
   }
   if(this.value != this.defaultValue){
       this.select();
      }
  }).bind("blur", function(event){
   $(this).removeClass("focusField").addClass("idleField");
      if ($.trim(this.value) == ''){
       this.value = (this.defaultValue ? this.defaultValue : '');
   }
  });

 });
```

this is not binding the events to new content - any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using `.bind`, use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$( document ).on( 'focus', 'input[type=text], textarea', function() {
    // stuff here will be applied to present and *future* elements
});
```

Comment: 10 / 10 - and what speed! - this is my first post - how do I award you the points?

Comment: Just to add, `input[type=text]` can be just `input:text` where :text is a [pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: I hope you don't mind I changed the answer to use `.on()` instead of the now deprecated methods.

Answer (score 1):

The [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method is for elements that currently exist. To attach event handlers to elements that currently exist in the DOM *and* any future elements that might exist you should use the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method. You can also use the [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method if you do not want your events to bubble all the way to the top of the DOM.

In addition, you can use the [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method to switch classes on your elements in one function call. Thus, your code would be:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type=text], textarea').addClass("idleField"); // reset all ##  
    $('input[type=text], textarea').live("focus", function(event){
        $(this).toggleClass("focusField idleField");
        if (this.value == this.defaultValue) { 
           this.value = '';
        }
        if (this.value != this.defaultValue) {
           this.select();
        }
    }).live("blur", function(event){
        $(this).toggleClass("focusField idleField");
          if ($.trim(this.value) == ''){
           this.value = (this.defaultValue ? this.defaultValue : '');
        }
    });
 });
```