# How to focus() after html()?

Tags: jquery, html, focus

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head><
<body>
    <button onClick="change()">Change Input</button>
    <div>
        <input value="It works">
    </div>

<script>
    function change() 
    {
        $('div').html('<input value="it didnt work">');
    }

    $('input').focus(function () 
    {
        if (this.value == this.defaultValue) 
        {
            this.value = '';
        }
    }).blur(function() 
    {
        if (this.value == '') 
        {
            this.value = this.defaultValue;
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here I try to focus an input after I change the html of a div. But it didn't work, why?

Comment: As you call it, focus isn't focusing the input but binding an event handler.

Comment: @poner Remove extra < from the code </head><

Comment: @dystroy: sorry im from germany, your comment seems to be important. but i cant get the point of it.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry from being from Germany... But Sushill explained it since : if you want to focus your input, don't pass parameters to the focus function.

Comment: ah okay. my problem isnt it to focus the input. my problem is that jquery/js didnt recognize after a $('div').html('NEW INPUT'); query that i focused the new input.
so the new input isnt present in dom before.

Comment: Use `$(document).on( 'focus', function() {...} );` instead. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery bind focus / blur events to AJAX loaded content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811433/jquery-bind-focus-blur-events-to-ajax-loaded-content)

Answer (score 0):

use `$('input').focus();` to focus on input box. make sure that input box is already present in dom.